# Release hidden objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, ios5, memory-leaks

I write app on iOS. I've got main class and `UIView` subclass with some `UILabel` fields.

I want to release memory when objects of subclass are out of the screen (I hide view by animation). How can I do this?

```
ViewController.h
#import "Histogram.h"
#import "HistogramDelegate.h"

{
UIScrollView *filtersScrollView;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture;
...some UILabels and other components.
Histogram *_Histogram;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Histogram *_Histogram;
... other properties
... some functions

@end


ViewController.m
-(void)viewDidLoad {
_Histogram = [[Histogram alloc] initWithFrame:...];
}
-(void)viewDidUnload // here i add nil value to objects, for ex. UIScrollView = nil.

-(void)someFunc {
 [_Histogram hideHistogram];
}

Histogram.h
//some objects/fields like UILabels, UISliders, UIViews


Histogram.m
some functions.
-(void)hideHistogram {

}
```

How and where can I release `_Histogram` and his objects from memory when are out of the screen? When I alloc and init `_Histogram` and when I hide `_Histogram`, my app is slower.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear. Anyways if you mean to ask how to free your memory once your histogram is hidden: then what you have to do is after calling `[_histogram _hidden]` call `[_histogram release]; _histogram=nil;`
Also in the `dealloc` function of your histogram.m file you should release all the elements you have initialized in that class. Otherwise releasing `_histogram` object wouldn't be of much help

Comment: yes, but when i type [_Histogram release] i've got error: 'release' is unavailable: not available in automatic reference counting mode : /

Comment: this is because you are using Automatic Reference Counting, which is by default enabled in the latest Xcode. So if you don't want _histogram, just make it to nil. That way u are not referring to it and it would be automatically released.

Comment: when i make _histogram = nil; application is still slow. i use S7GraphView library in histogram. Should i make nil 3 arrays in his method? all S7GraphView functions are initialized in Histogram. maybe this make my app slow.

Comment: I am not familiar with the S&GraphView library. But I really doubt that it is causing you the slowness. If you think the UI is sluggish, it might be because the way you are handling things in the main thread. Using some extra memory would never make your app slow.

Comment: i must learn how to use threads and i'll check it. thanks for help.